# Read one line from .txt file and insert into variable

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I am trying to write a program that will read just the first line of my textfile and then input that number into an int variable. But im confused as how to do it.

```
    int highscore; // Starting highscore

  ifstream myfile ("highscore.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline(myfile,highscore);
      cout << highscore << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
```

But for some reason im getting the error. `|25|error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, int&)'|`

Comment: to find the namespace of getline function, like your std::ifstream

Comment: std:: is the namespace that getline is from, if you havnt done `using namespace standard` then you need to use std before your getline call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the getline with:

```
if (myfile >> highscore)
    cout << "Read " << highscore << '\n';
else
    cout << "Couldn't read an int\n";
```

You'll be able to read an int into highscore.  Are you required to use getline?

Comment: Works perfect but i tweaked it a but without the if and else statements :) so why didnt getline work?

Comment: Billz answer explains that pretty well.  You'll need to read it into a string first and then convert that to an int.